# Topological manifold and a subset

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $A,B$ be two $n$-dimensional topological manifolds with $\varnothing \neq A \subset B$. Assume that $A,B$ are closed manifolds. Is it possible that $A \cong B$ and $A \neq B$?

Comment: Hint: a topological embedding between equidimensional manifolds is an open map.

Answer (score 0):

Show that we may assume wlog that $X$ is connected. Then arrive at a contradiction, e.g., by considering a path from a point $\notin Y$ to a point $\in Y$.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you spelled this out.